# Will Shortest_paths considerate all paths to a same name vertex, however with different index ID?

Tags: igraph

I have a vertex named "A" and other one with the same name "A", however with different index_ids, if there is a vertex called "X" and i do:

```
 graph.get_all_shortest_paths("X", "A" , mode = 'out')
```

Will it return the shortest path considering X to A¹ and X to A², or only the first one that igraph "see", since igraph already did the last option, when connecting edges.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that igraph defaults to the lowest id if there are vertices with the same name. see below:

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(8675309)
el <- data.frame(to=sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 10, replace = T), 
                 from = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 10, 
                 replace = T))
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(el))
g1 <- add_vertices(g, 2, attr = list(name = c("A","X" )))
g1 <- add_edges(g1, c(7,1, 7,4, 4,6, 2,1))
V(g1)[[]]
#+ 7/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#  name
#1    A
#2    E
#3    C
#4    D
#5    B
#6    A
#7    X
plot(g1, vertex.label = make.unique(V(g1)$name))
```

[image]

First we check for shortest paths with the first A vertex is closest.

```
get.all.shortest.paths(g1, from = "X", to = "A")
#$res[[1]]
#+ 2/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] X A

get.all.shortest.paths(g1, from = "X", to = V(g1)[name=="A"])
#$res[[1]]
#+ 2/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] X A
#
#$res[[2]]
#+ 3/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] X D A
```

Then we check the shortest path when the second A (A.1) vertex is closest and notice that the path to the first A is reported even though it is longer.

```
get.all.shortest.paths(g1, from = "D", "A")
#$res[[1]]
#+ 3/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] D E A

get.all.shortest.paths(g1, from = "D", V(g1)[name=="A"])
#$res[[1]]
#+ 3/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] D E A
# 
#$res[[2]]
#+ 2/7 vertices, named, from f23a782:
#[1] D A
```